# Logstash Individual Key parsing

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a field which is of type string and holds a log data from which I need to identify specific fields as below. What could be the best way to do this when string doesn't have a fixed delimiter

```
"Log": "2016-01-01T00:00:12|DEBUG|89ID:701Task':
ID=701125351 wayID=666 iceID=688 UID=733008 MID=00D089DE DName=null 
......................................
```

(This is one column value in MYSQL and I am trying to pull from MYSQL in ES ..)
the data above is stored in a field called `outputdata`. I have to read a field like `UID=733008` from it. Is there a way in logstash that can read the matching words as UID and save that UID field in an index.

Comment: After grokking your log message, you can leverage the [`kv`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) filter in order to slice and dice your key-values pairs into fields.

Comment: Awesome..It's working :)

Comment: Of course it is, glad you figured it out :)